# How to validate username and password in android using symbols?

Tags: java, android

I have difficulties when validating the username and password, they may not use the desired symbol.

Example special **character** : **`@,.<>/?'";:[{]}\|+=_-)(*&^%$#@!~`** and so forth.

But I want to validate the username and password that I want.

I only want the username allowed to use 1 symbol and 1 space, and the passwords should allowed to use 1 capital letter.

my code

```
        if (username.matches("")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Username no valid.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (password.matches("")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password no valid.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Maybe someone here can help my problem.

Comment: Please define what a "symbol" means here.

Comment: Validation symbol of the register or login form, may only use permitted symbols

Comment: I think that symbols and special characters are the same with mention of words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using Regex

```
public static boolean isValidPassword(final String password) {

    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;
    final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(password);

    return matcher.matches();

}
```

> later you can check

```
 if(!isValidPassword(newPassword.getText().toString())){
//error msg
   }else{
//your work
}
```

Comment: Do you have a valid password sample? I will use the sample password that you gave me

Comment: Try this password fwf1Q!e1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205847/discussion-between-isuru-and-aing-macan).

Answer (score 0):

Use below regex for minimum eight characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character -

```
public static boolean checkPassword(String pass) {
Pattern pat;
Matcher mat;
String PASSWORD= "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$";
pat= Pattern.compile(PASSWORD);
mat= pattern.matcher(pass);
return mat.matches();
}
```

this will help you

Answer (score 0):

**Use Regular this Expression: for USERNAME** 
replace **$%#@#**  with special char that you want

```
String regularExpression1 = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[\\s]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*[$%#@#]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
String regularExpression2 = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[$%#@#]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*[\\s]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";

if (userName.matches(regularExpression1) || userName.matches(regularExpression2) ) {
                    System.out.println("Valid");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid");
                }
```

For password : edit regex **[A-Z]{1}** that allow only one Capital Char.